# How do I create a horizontal floating div that is always on the bottom of the page, no matter how the user scrolls?

Tags: css, templates

I just want that horizontal div (about 50 pixels tall) that span across the entire bottom of the page always. How?

Comment: Bottom of the page, or bottom of the browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `position: fixed` feature in your CSS.

```
.footer {
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
}
```

However that does not work with IE6; [check this link for a workaround](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at position:fixed;  I've used it to do this before, but you'll run into a cross browser bug with IE.  I ended up using a CSS _expression() hack so that it worked in IE6/7.